# client and php server side validation

Tags: php, validation, class, server, client

I'm starting developing a new application and I'm think about client and server side validation. Client side validation is all sorted but obviously I want to make sure everything is still correct once it reaches the server.

I was thinking about creating classes and using the setters to validate the data before doing anything. If there were any errors I would record those in an array inside the class which could be checked before taking any action.

Does this sound like a reasonable approach or am I going down the wrong path?

Thanks, Andy

Answer (score 0):

Google is full of tutorials on how to validate data on server side [this](http://w3epic.com/how-to-validate-form-with-php-server-side-validation/) is one of them.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do it but google might tell me the best practise and if my approach is a good idea.